# Two list items out of four not working fine. while it's fine with the other two?

Tags: html, css, button

Two of my list items - Profile and Alerts - are not responding to CSS rule and h ref. It doesn't show transition on hover and are not clickable.
If anyone can help me in the problem stated above.

```css
.uList {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.listItem {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /*text-transform: uppercase;*/
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid #009688;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
  transition: .3s;
  position: relative;
}

.btn:before {
  color: #009688;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #009688;
  opacity: .5;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .3s;
}

.btn:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #009688;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .3s;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover:before {
  top: 0;
}

.btn:hover:after {
  top: 0;
}

.btn {
  color: #009688;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="uList">
    <li class="listItem"><a class="btn" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="listItem"><a class="btn" href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="listItem"><a class="btn" href="Alerts.php">Alerts</a></li>
    <li class="listItem"><a class="btn" href="index.php?logout='1'">Logout</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: seems to work in your example. what is wrong?

Comment: Is `Alerts.php` supposed to be capitalized? Or is it actually `alerts.php`?

Comment: its doesnt work on my xampp local host. the way "home" and "logout" list items have transitions on hover , neither profile nor Alert do have it.

Comment: @zer00ne Alerts and profile do not show transitions on hover like others. plus when i click on them they don't respond at any cost

Comment: @AyubJamal on Chrome everything appears to function properly. It might be a typo perhaps? Does this code work for you on this site like it does for tech2017 and I?

Comment: @zer00ne actually it does work for me too. but still have problem on localhost Xampp

Comment: its hard to troubleshoot. double check in inspector, try changing z-index may be.

Comment: That narrows it down a bit, unfortunately XAMP isn't my forte. You'll get more responses if you add XAMP as a tag probably.

Comment: having said that all of my inputs fields have some how lost vertical bar by default. and dont even appear on double click